# Nested Calculations

Tags: excel, vba, range, defined

I'm trying to make a complicated formula display its calculated values in excel formula bar.

For example this `=(D9* AE9)+(A9-E9)` be displayed like this `=(4*0.88)+(3-1)`.

I would really appreciate your help on this!

Thank you in advance

Comment: `="=("&D9&"*"&AE9&")+("&A9&"-"&E9&")"`

Comment: Hello there again thank you so much or your response!!!                                       
Thats a great idea althought i wasnt so clear in my initial post. Sorry about that :( .                                                    
What i need is:  the total value ( 5.52) appear on cell and at the same time the formula bar displaying calculation  (4*0.88)+(3-1)  instead of =(D9* AE9)+(A9-E9) when value 5.52 is selected

Comment: `cell.Formula = "=(" & Range("D9").Value & "*" & Range("AE9").Value & ")+(" & Range("A9").Value & "-" & Range("E9").Value & ")"` Remember to fully qualify your range reference or else it will refer to ActiveSheet which might not be what you want. @ABB

Answer (score 0):

The Excel Formula Bar always show the formula in the active cell - you cannot use VBA to permanently change one without changing the other.

If you select a portion of the formula (a subexpression) in the formula bar and press F9 excel will show you the result of evaluating that subexpression (remember to press Escape to revert back to the formula).

If you are looking for a way of understanding/troubleshooting complex formulas try Excel's built-in Evaluate Formula tool on the Formulas tab.

There are also more powerful formula explorer addin tools available commercially. These use formula parsers and evaluaters to show the user what the parts of the formula resolve to.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help sir i really appreciate your time.